# Script terminates reading before end of file

Tags: python, binary, ascii

I am trying to read a file that contains an ASCII header and binary data sections, but the Python interpreter appears to close the file prematurely (i.e. before the end of file is reached). Here is my code, developed in Python 2.7.12:

```
fileSize = os.path.getsize(filename) # file size in bytes
bytesRead = 0L
content = []
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    bytesRead += sys.getsizeof(content)

print 'File size:',fileSize
print 'Total read:',bytesRead
```

However, the file is closed prematurely after around 1MB of the total 77MB of the file has been read.

```
print 'File size:',fileSize
print 'Total read:',bytesRead
```

produces: `File size: 76658457, Total read: 1165436`

It exits within one of the binary sections. I moified the original program to iteratively re-open the file from the point that it was closed, as follows:

```
fileSize = os.path.getsize(filename) # file size in bytes
bytesRead = 0L
content = []

try:
    while True:
        count += 1
        with open(filename,'r') as f:
            f.seek(bytesRead+1)
            newContent = f.read()
            content.append(newContent)
            bytesRead += sys.getsizeof(newContent)
            print count,' Total read:',bytesRead
except Exception,e:
    print e

print 'File size:',fileSize
print '% read = ',bytesRead*100./float(fileSize)
print 'count: ',count
```

This gave:

```
1 Total read: 1165436
2 Total read: 1180218
3 Total read: 1181902

... [many more iterations] ...

25564 Total read: 77925641
25567 Total read: 77926615
25568 Total read:Exception: I/O operation on closed file

File size: 76658457
% read =  101.65429721603
count:  25568
```

Any idea how I can persuade Python not to keep closing the file, and just read it all in one go?

Comment: This is an odd output. First, you don't even increment `count`, how can those `print` commands print `1`, `2`, `3` etc? Second, Python 2.7 docs explicitly state that, when `read()` is called without arguments, it will read the whole file (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). Are you sure the code you are showing is the one which is actually being executed?

Comment: Some OSs, like Windows, handle reading text files differently than binary files. For example, in the way they handle newline characters. Windows text files can also have an EOF (end-of-file) character in them. It looks like your code is reading the file in the default text mode. Try opening the file in binary mode with `with open(filename,'rb') as f:`

Comment: You need to open the file in binary mode. When you don't include the `b` under mode, python will alter the content of the file, possibly inserting an EOF or newline.

Comment: Never use ``sys.getsizeof()``.  In your case you want to use ``len()``.

Comment: Added the increment to count - otherwise code is the one that produced the output. I'll test it shortly, but I suspect the answer is to open the file in binary mode, as suggested by martineau.

Comment: Note that I'm comparing the total number of bytes on the file to the number of bytes that has been read. So I don't think len() would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

What I believe to be happening is that you are checking the byte size, rather than the actual data in the array. Check the last line of the array, and then the last line of the file, and it will most likely reveal the fact that it is in fact reading the entire file